# Using Async/Await in firebase | react-redux | react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, react-native

The code works, but I was wondering if someone could help me translate that into a better async/await syntax.

The code is fetching data using firebase api and handling the response with react-redux and thunk middleware.

I'm building an React-Native app. The "forEach" in "childSnapshot" is where I can't seem to make it neater, and I needed that to sort the score values in JSON => [Node.js + Firebase orderByChild not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382225/node-js-firebase-orderbychild-not-working)

```
  export const getScores = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    let res =[];
    await firebase.database().ref("game_score_ref").orderByChild("score").once("value", snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>{
        res.push(childSnapshot.toJSON())
      })
    });
    dispatch({ type: GET_SCORES, payload: res });
  }catch(err){
    dispatch({ type: GET_SCORES_ERROR, payload: err });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sort `res` after the forEach loop perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getScores = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const score = await firebase.database().ref("game_score_ref").orderByChild("score")
    return score.once("value", snapshot => {
      const res = snapshot.map(childSnapshot => childSnapshot.toJSON())
      return dispatch({ type: GET_SCORES, payload: res });
    })
  }catch(err){
    dispatch({ type: GET_SCORES_ERROR, payload: err });
  }
}
```

Give this a try. I wrote something very similar for a personal project with firebase.

Comment: It looks lot better, but it gives me this err: "snapshot.map is not a function." I think I have to use the built-in DataSnapshot.forEach() method if I understood this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382225/node-js-firebase-orderbychild-not-working) correctly. But thank you!